# Pandas selecting dataframe columns using a specific string and array/list

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with hundreds of columns (stocks). My issue is that I need to always pull a specific column (date) followed by an array/list of others (dynamic).

Previously I was doing something like this:

```
df = stocks[['date', 'AAPL', 'AMZN']]
```

but now if I need to dynamically choose stocks based on a sector I am not sure how to make these play nice together. I am only able to pull the list without using date like this:

```
print(rowData['symbol'])
3    [APA.OQ, BKR.N, COG.N, CVX.N, CXO.N, COP.N, DV...
Name: symbol, dtype: object

selection = rowData['symbol'].explode()
df = stocks[selection]
```

how do I also get the date values? something like this doesn't work:

```
df = stocks[['date'][selection]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try

```
df = stocks[['date'] + rowData['symbol'].iloc[0]]
```